# Sudden spike in database server I/O

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL database server which is keeps spiking to 84% disk I/O anywhere from roughly 10pm => 12am. There does not appear to be a sudden rush of traffic to the site, in fact we are able to cope throughout the day with considerably more traffic no problem.

The only way to stop the issue happening, is to simply reset the server.

I'm seeing various log messages such as the ones below:

```
[Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 4104ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=1 and evicted=12, during the time.)
[Note] Aborted connection *** to db: '***' user: '***' host: '***' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

However I am having difficulty in tracing firstly why these are being caused, and secondly whether or not they are the root of my problem.

Why might this be occurring at roughly the same time each night?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you enabled slow log?

Comment: Does site usage also increase at all?

Comment: @ChrisBint we have New Relic installed on the server which reports a bunch of slow queries, however I am unsure as to whether or not one or more are causing the issue, or are being caused by the issue. Would enabling slow log turn up anything more? Many thanks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen quite the opposite. We are looking at somewhere between one third to half of the maximum traffic we see throughout the day.

Comment: Sounds like the backups maybe happening?

Comment: @BugFinder I have a cron job backing up the database at 3am every morning, but nothing is scheduled to run at that time in the evening.

Comment: You dont have server backups of the OS running?